# Exclude tasks from development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I have this block in the deploy namespace:

```
 if :stage != :development then
    before :check, 'deploy:open'
    after :restart, 'deploy:close'
  end
```

however, this is not working. Is there a way to exclude tasks from a given stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Capistrano 3, you are supposed to use `fetch` to get a variable.

```
if fetch(:stage) != :development
```

should work.